# Where does $\Lambda=P^{-1}AP$ come from?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we derive the fact that if a matrix is diagonalizable then we can diagonalize it with the formula $\Lambda = P^{-1}AP$, where $P$ is a block matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$?

I can see that if you start with $A$ and multiply by $P=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_k\end{bmatrix}$, then you end up with $AP = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1v_1 & \lambda_2v_2 & \cdots & \lambda_kv_k\end{bmatrix}$.  I don't see why the next step should be to left multiply by $P^{-1}$.

Also, even if the formula $\Lambda = P^{-1}AP$ holds, how do we know this is the *only* why to produce a diagonal matrix from $A$?  Perhaps $A$ is also similar to a diagonal matrix whose entries are *not* the eigenvalues of $A$ (but still the product of whose diagonal entries is the determinant of $A$).  How can we prove that this is not possible -- or if it is possible, why is it not ever mentioned?

Comment: It is change of variable. If $f:E\to E$ given by $y=f(x)=Ax$ and we change variables in the domain $x=Px'$ and in the target $y=Py'$ we get $Py'=APx'$, from where $y'=P^{-1}APx'$. Diagonalizable means that in some coordinates the matrix is diagonal. "Some coordinates" means that you are allowed, and only allowed, to change variables to new coordinates. One changes to new coordinates in linear algebra by applying an invertible linear transformation $x=Px'$.

Comment: It's not possible for $A$ to be similar to a diagonal matrix whose entries are not the eigenvalues because similarity transformations preserve eigenvalues (along with both their algebraic and geometric multiplicity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the $2 \times 2$ case you can generalize:

Suppose $A$ is an arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix with two eigenvalues, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, and hence two corresponding eigenvectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$. Define a matrix $P$ whose columns are those two eigenvectors,

\begin{equation} P =\left( \begin{matrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) \end{equation}
where those vertical bars indicate the column.

Then the action of $A$ on $P$ is the same as the action of $A$ on the individual columns. As those columns are also eigenvectors we may write

\begin{equation} AP =\left( \begin{matrix} Av_1 & Av_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1v_1 & \lambda_2v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) =  \underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right)}_{P} \underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right)}_{\Lambda} \end{equation}

where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. That is, $AP = P\Lambda$. As $P$ is invertible (why?) we may write

\begin{equation} A = P\Lambda P^{-1} \end{equation}

or

\begin{equation} \Lambda = P^{-1}A P \end{equation}

---

On the uniqueness of the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$, see Ian's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(e_1 \dots e_n)$ us the usual basis, and $X_k$ the $k$th column of the matrix $X$.

If $P^{-1}AP = D$ is diagonal, then taking the $k$th column of $P$ you get that:
$$
(P^{-1}AP)_k =
P^{-1}AP_k = D_k = \lambda_k e_k
\\ \implies AP_k = \lambda_k\times P e_k = \lambda_k P_k
$$
So the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors for $A$.

Comment: Interesting.  You proved it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to see with eigenvectors: it is the general change of basis formula for linear maps.

Let me give some details: suppose a linear map $f$ has matrix $A$ in some basis $\mathcal B$. Let $mathcal B'$ another basis; denote as $P$ the matrix with column vector $C_i$ equal to the coordinates (in basis $\mathcal B$) of the $i$-th vector of $\mathcal B'$. $P$ is called the *change of basis matrix from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$*.

Now for any vector $x$ with column matrix $X$ in basis $\mathcal B$, $X'$ in $\mathcal B'$, one has:
$$X=PX'$$
Let $Y$ the column vector of $f(x)$ in basis $\mathcal B$. $Y$  and $X$  are related by $Y=AX$. Similarly if  $Y'$ is the column vector of $f(x)$ in basis $\mathcal B'$, one has $Y=PY'$.

Thus we can write:
$$Y=PY'=AX=A(PX'),\enspace\text{whence}\quad Y'=(P^{-1}AP)X$$
This proves the matrix of $f$  in basis $\mathcal B'$ is:
$$A'=P^{-1}AP.$$